# PHP Update script with empty value check

Tags: php, database, pdo

I got this PHP script with a Empty value check.
But for some reason when i added a hyperlink in my TD it don't update my values anymore.

Can you guys please help me?

### edit.php

```html
<?php
require_once('connect.php');

$newKenteken = $_POST['kenteken'];
$newMerk = $_POST['merk'];
$newType = $_POST['type'];
$newBouwjaar = $_POST['bouwjaar'];
$newTenaamstellingdatum = $_POST['tenaamstellingdatum'];
$newGewicht = $_POST['gewicht'];
$newToelatingdatum = $_POST['toelatingdatum'];
$newAfgiftedatum = $_POST['afgiftedatum'];
$id = $_POST['memids'];

if ( empty($kenteken) || empty($merk) || empty($type) || empty($bouwjaar) || empty($tenaamstellingdatum) || empty($gewicht) || empty($toelatingdatum) || empty($afgiftedatum) ) {
  echo "U bent wat vergeten in te vullen of u heeft niks ingevuld.";
  header("refresh: 3; url=index.php");
 } else {
  $sql = "UPDATE voertuig 
    SET kenteken=?, merk=?, type=?, bouwjaar=?, tenaamstellingdatum=?, gewicht=?, toelatingdatum=?, afgiftedatum=?
    WHERE vid=?";
  $q = $db->prepare($sql);
  $q->execute(array($newKenteken,$newMerk,$newType,$newBouwjaar,$newTenaamstellingdatum,$newGewicht,$newToelatingdatum,$newAfgiftedatum,$id));
  header("location: index.php");
 }
?>
```

### editform.php

```html
<?php
 require_once('connect.php');
 require_once('navi.php');
 require_once('style.css');
 $id=$_GET['id'];
 $result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM voertuig WHERE vid= :id");
 $result->bindParam(':id', $id);
 $result->execute();
 for($i=0; $row = $result->fetch(); $i++){
?>
 <form action="edit.php" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="memids" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />
  Kenteken<br>
  <input type="text" name="kenteken" value="<?php echo $row['kenteken']; ?>" /><br>
  Merk<br>
  <input type="text" name="merk" value="<?php echo $row['merk']; ?>" /><br>
  Type<br>
  <input type="text" name="type" value="<?php echo $row['type']; ?>" /><br>
  Bouwjaar<br>
  <input type="text" name="bouwjaar" value="<?php echo $row['bouwjaar']; ?>" /><br>
  Tenaamstellingdatum<br>
  <input type="date" name="tenaamstellingdatum" value="<?php echo $row['tenaamstellingdatum']; ?>" /><br>
  Gewicht<br>
  <input type="text" name="gewicht" value="<?php echo $row['gewicht']; ?>" /><br>
  Toelatingdatum<br>
  <input type="date" name="toelatingdatum" value="<?php echo $row['toelatingdatum']; ?>" /><br>
  Afgiftedatum<br>
  <input type="date" name="afgiftedatum" value="<?php echo $row['afgiftedatum']; ?>" />
  <input type="submit" value="Save" />
 </form>
<?php
 }
?>
```

### table_voertuig.php

```html
<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" >
<thead>
 <tr>
  <th> Kenteken </th>
  <th> Merk </th>
  <th> Type </th>
  <th> Bouwjaar </th>
  <th> Tenaamstellingdatum </th>
  <th> Gewicht </th>
  <th> Toelatingdatum </th>
  <th> Afgiftedatum </th>
 </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
 <?php
  require_once('connect.php');
  $result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM voertuig ORDER BY vid DESC");
  $result->execute();
  for($i=0; $row = $result->fetch(); $i++){
 ?>
 <tr class="record">
  <td><a href="editform.php?id=<?php echo $row['vid']; ?>"><?php echo $row['kenteken']; ?></a></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['merk']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['type']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['bouwjaar']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['tenaamstellingdatum']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['gewicht']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['toelatingdatum']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['afgiftedatum']; ?></td>
 </tr>
 <?php
  }
 ?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: can you please only paste the parts that have issues

Comment: That's the problem i don't really know where the problem is or wich parts have issues

Comment: are you using `edit.php` or `editform.php` to update the db?

Comment: edit.php is the script what sends the information to the database. the editform.php script is to get the information out the database to change it.

Comment: ok great, give m few mins

Comment: Sure! take your time and thank you :)

Comment: on the form are you actually getting the records of the id that i selected from the $_GET?

Comment: Yes, the id is 1 it says.

Comment: and the form does show values? if yes then the problem should be in edit.php

Comment: yes, it shows all the values. But when i want to change a value it activates my empty check. "U bent wat vergeten in te vullen of u heeft niks ingevuld."

Comment: i've solved it, i got $merk instead of $newMerk same goes for the other $ in my empty check